# Does Swift async HTTP request create another thread?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, asynchronous, swift3

I have two questions.

First one is "Does swift async http request create another thread"?

Second problem is that I have a table view and after my http request, I need to refresh my tableview based on the data I retrieved from server. However, if I do self.tableview?.reloadData outside of the dispatch_async closure, it won't work. (It would refresh after a long time).

So my question is why does that happen? Why can't I refresh the tableview just in that thread without going back to main thread?

I have been looking for explanation of swift http request and its mechanism for a while. I would really appreciate if anyone would like to explain it more in details!

I have attached my working code below

```
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://xxx/getAllposts.php")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "user=ios"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in
        if error != nil {

            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        print("response = \(response)")
        let responseString = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary
        if responseString!["success"] as! Int == 0{
            return
        }

        let array:NSArray = responseString!["all"] as! NSArray

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] in
            self.values = array
            self.tableView?.reloadData();

        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: I do understand half of this problem. I know first the http request creates a background thread. But is it why it's also known as an "async request". Did the other thread makes it async?

Comment: Note that the `dispatch_async()` syntax has been changed to `DispatchQueue.main.async()` in Swift 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't really about "Swift async HTTP request", but rather about `NSURLSession` (OR `URLSession` in Swift 3.) You can call NSURLSEssion from Swift, from Objective-C, and probably from C++ or C. The language doesn't matter.

`NSURLSession` support asynchronous network requests. That means that the "heavy lifting" is done in the background while your program continues to run. Async APIs are almost always written to do their work on a background thread, but there are other ways to do the same thing. (On older hardware async communications might be handled using interrupts, for example.)

Under the covers, `NSURLSession` uses a pool of shared threads to do the work. So it does do it's network transactions on a separate thread, but it doesn't create a unique thread for that purpose (Creating threads is pretty expensive in terms of time and system resources. It's much more efficient to maintain a pool of shared threads and use them as needed for things like this.)

Once the task is complete, NSURLSession tells the caller about it. It can do this via a completion handler or a delegate. Both completion methods and delegate methods are executed on a serial operation queue. (known as the delegate queue in both cases.) By default NSURLSession creates that operation queue for you, and it runs on a background thread. If you use the default `NSURLSession` I don't think you can change the delegate queue. If you create your own `NSURLSession` you can set it up to use a dispatch queue that runs on the main thread, but I would not recommend it. It's a good thing to do data processing on a background thread.

This means that normally the messages sent to you about your task are sent on a background thread.

Most UIKit calls must be run on the main thread. If you don't, the results are undefined (Ranging from long delays in the UI update taking effect to crashes and other strange behavior.)

A call like `tableView.reloadData()` must be done on the main thread. That's why you have to wrap it in a call to `DispatchQueue.main.async()`

Comment: I really appreciate your answer! Very comprehensive! One last question tho, I tried to refresh the tableview outside the DispatchQueue.main.async() and it would still refresh except it takes a long time. So I wonder if I call tableView.reloadData() on the background thread right after I get the data from server without going back to the main thread, it would wait until the execution in that thread is done before it actually refreshes the table?

Comment: See this part of my answer: "Most UIKit calls must be run on the main thread. If you don't, the results are undefined (**Ranging from long delays in the UI update taking effect** to crashes and other strange behavior.)" That is a symptom of doing a UI update from the background. You can't be certain what will happen. Sometimes it even works, but most of the time something bad happens. Don't do it. It's like having a surgeon do open heart surgery on somebody while he's doing sit-ups. It might go ok, but if the patient moves at the wrong time, it could end very badly.

Comment: Clean! U also mentioned using completion handler. I experimented that by updating the UI in the completion closure. That way I could make sure the data is all processed before I tried to update UI. But it gave me the same result which takes a long time to update the UI. So I assume if I try to reload tableview even in the completion closure, it's still doing it in the background thread?